# Open link in new window, not in the iframe

Tags: html, jsf, iframe

I have an HTML file that contain iframe, say (called a.html):

```
<body>
<iframe width="430" height="220" frameborder="0" 
    src="http://www.et.co.il/jsp/callIframe.jsf">
</iframe>
</body>
```

In callIframe.jsf file there is a link.
when a user press this link i want that the link will open in a new window.
if i leave it like that, it opens inside the iframe...

I can not change a.html file. i can do changes inside the jsf only.

Comment: post that link that you have in the jsf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Java Scirpt.

I used the method window.open(URL,name,specs,replace).

This method can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 2):

is this is what you are looking for?

```
<h:outputLink value="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">CNN</h:outputLink>
```

or this

```
<h:link outcome="pageNameGoesHere" target="_blank">SomePage</h:link>
```

or this

```
<h:commandLink target="_blank" action="#{bean.somePage}" value="Some Page" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
<base target="_blank" />;
```

Comment: This is odd. This has worked for me in the past, but doesn't work for my current page. I don't think this is the best answer because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works :) Looks like an invite for XSS...

### I think currently ALL browsers will stop you from doing so...

Oops... I thought you meant to execute a link from within the IFrame by adding something to to caller (html)... Instead this seems perfectly ok..

you could indeed use <base target...> for this.

Comment: Do you need to be inside the IFRAME ? Or could you brake out it .. I still do not see any trace of the base target inside the link you provided.... <head> <base href="http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp" target="_blank" /> </head>